# Nuxt Cannot load payload _payload.js TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier '_payload.js'

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In My project, nuxt3 version is  `"nuxt": "^3.0.0-rc.10",`

Everything is ok on my dev server. But when I generate pages using `npm run generate` and serve using `npm run preview` I get this below error,

```
entry.a89924e4.js:5 [nuxt] Cannot load payload  _payload.js TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier '_payload.js'
    at entry.a89924e4.js:5:30975
    at ht (entry.a89924e4.js:5:30106)
    at qk (entry.a89924e4.js:5:30968)
    at Hk (entry.a89924e4.js:5:30683)
    at e (entry.a89924e4.js:3072:7911)
    at entry.a89924e4.js:3072:8045
    at entry.a89924e4.js:1:78708
    at async Promise.all (:45915/index 0)
    at async entry.a89924e4.js:5:32621
```

I don't know from where this error might be generated.

Comment: Does it also happen on `3.0.0-rc.11`? Can you provide a reproduction?

Comment: Just updated to rc.11 getting same error. I will try to provide a reproduction as soon as possible.

Comment: I have used  hash(#) in my unused link i.e `<nuxt-link to="#">Link</nuxt-link>` That is one of the reason I am getting error in generated file.

Comment: Yes, it solved my above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP had a remaining `<nuxt-link to="#">Link</nuxt-link>` somewhere in the codebase.
Removing it fixed the build issue.